# Using Aggregate Expression in QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-modeler

I want to create a graphical model in QGIS. The model will input a polygon and a point layer and then add an attribute to the polygon that counts the number of points inside (intersects). I know that in the past, it was not possible to include aggregate functions in the model (As said by developer Nyall Dawson: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30397#issuecomment-505699624).

What is the use of exposing the outputs (*_OUTPUT, *_OUTPUT_maxx, etc.) of various processing steps in the expression engine inside the graphical model?

Here is the model:
[image]

[Here](https://app.box.com/s/ev98ypxcyasc29yxunattgypfz4c9zme) is the model file:

And [here](https://app.box.com/s/gc6zccrfu43spz48khvfgxhvf587ydsq) is the `gpkg` file you may use.

Why does the model fail with this message?

> Could not evaluate the expression for parameter FORMULA for GetCount:
> Cannot find the layer with name or ID ''.

I seek a solution using the Graphical Modeler.